# Am trying to set sambashare path to whole computer

Tags: networking, command-line, samba

I just switched from Macos to Ubuntu and am trying to connect my devices with smb over lan. The connection works but only the "sambashare" folder is being shared.

```
path = /home/username/sambashare
```

How can I put my whole ubuntu computer including connected external harddrives in this path?

Comment: I did find the answer. I found that in the GUI, rightclick on the disk you want to share, under properties, there is a 'local network share' option. Set it to share there and it is seen by my mac and android phone.

Comment: Just found out the real problem. sudo chown does not work on hfs+ disks, but acts as if it is working. Therefore I did not manage to own the files and was not allowed to share.